# Parallelising function on struct array in OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm currently writing an N-body gravitation and simulation code. After successfully implementing a few integrators and force codes for single core use, I decided to try my hand at multithreading with OpenMP. Given I'm very new to OpenMP, questions regarding shared memory and certain technical nuances go well beyond me at the moment.

My code uses a struct state, given by

```c
typedef struct state {
    int num_particles;
    particle* particles;

    octree *ot;
    params sim_cfg;

} state;
```

The main thing to note for the moment being the particle list, which contains all of my point particles for the simulation. The code I am currently trying to parallelise is my direct method force code which naively computes the forces between every particle pair

```c
void direct(state *sim) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < sim->num_particles; i++) {
        sim->particles[i].acc = (vec3){0,0,0};
        direct_acc(&sim->particles[i], *sim);
    }
}

void direct_acc(particle *p, state sim) {
    for(int j = 0; j < sim.num_particles; j++) {
        if(p == sim.particles+j)
            continue;
        p->acc = vec_add(p->acc, vec_scale(fg_calc(*p, sim.particles[j], sim.sim_cfg), 1/p->mass));
    }
}
```

Every trial I've run produces the results I expect. However, I see absolutely 0 speed increase between different thread counts, at least measured using `time` in the console.

```
1 thread
real    0m0.816s
user    0m0.815s
sys     0m0.001s
```

```
2 threads
real    0m0.826s
user    0m0.825s
sys     0m0.000s`
```

```
4 threads
real    0m0.855s
user    0m0.854s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I I've been sure to compile with `-fopenmp` and have been able to successfully reimplement several example programs on various websites. As far as I can tell nothing of the code I have written should result in any conflicts between threads, but I could be very wrong about that. All this is to say, I would greatly appreciate any help on this, as I've been stuck on the issue for quite a long time and would in general like to understand better why the OpenMP isn't working as I expect it to

Edit: As per PierU's suggestion, I recomputed the runtimes using the standard OMP functions, however the results didn't change much.

```
1 thread
Elapsed time 0.822067s
```

```
2 threads
Elapsed time 0.870764s
```

```
4 threads
Elapsed time 0.823142s
```

**Resolution**:
The issue came down to how openmp was being compiled. I was compiling all my files separately in a makefile, and the -fopenmp flag was only being set on the target. However many times I used `omp_set_num_threads()`, `omp_get_num_threads()` always returned 1. Having all the files compile with -fopenmp fixed the issue. Here's some performance metrics to boot! (1000 particles for 1000 timesteps)

```
1 thread
Elapsed time 13.406991s
```

```
2 threads
Elapsed time 6.908134s
```

```
4 threads
Elapsed time 4.112684s
```

```
8 threads
Elapsed time 3.058720s
```

```
12 threads
Elapsed time 2.328875s
```

Thanks to everyone for the help, even if it was a silly compilation error on my part.

Comment: I think that `time` measures the cumulative CPU time for all the threads. You need to measure the elapse time, not the CPU time. For this you can use the `omp_get_wtime()` function in your code.

Comment: I just redid those runs using `omp_get_wtime()` (thanks!) and yet alas, very similar results. The original post has been updated with the new times

Comment: How many particles do you have in your example?

Comment: 100 particles for 1000 timesteps. If I was using a tree code like the Barnes-Hut algorithm the reduction in computations would be so drastic as to make the total compute time negligible (< 100 ms), but using the O(N^2) direct method increases the computations enough where it is quite noticeable, and where parallelisation would be quite useful (and as I would imagine, just as noticeable)

Comment: I'm doubtful you're actually running in multi-threads. Indeed, if so, as `time` gives elapsed as "real" and cpu as "user", I would expect that "user" would increase. Can you double check OpenMP is indeed active?

Comment: Note that threads read and write to same `particle` object at the same time. It usually results in non-deterministic computation, often producing wrong results.

Comment: What's really fascinating is that I have no indication from openmp that it isn't active, I'm using -fopenmp in my makefile and I can successfully compile other programs featuring omp, yet forcing it to print the number of active threads inside the loop reveals that indeed only one is active. As per your point @tstanisl, it was my understanding that how OpenMP generally handled loops by assigning each thread to unique iterator values, so as long as no step in the loop required anything from other threads, there wouldn't be conflicts?

Comment: N^2=10000 is maybe not enough to take advantage of multithreading. But I'm not sure either if OpenMP is active here. Even when no speed-up is obtained, it's quite rare to have an elapse time that does not vary with the number of threads.

Comment: How do you set the number of threads ?

Comment: What I understand from your code is that you are updating only the acceleration of the particles. As long as the acceleration is not used in turn within the loops, there should not be any race condition issue.

Comment: Well it seems the error came in the fact that my make file wasn't compiling dependencies with openmp! Doing so results in expected performance increases that I'll specify in an edit in case this proves useful to anyone else in the future. Thank you all for your help and comments!

Comment: A more general comment is that it looks as if you may be doing twice the amount of work you need to, since you seem to be calculating both the force between particle a and particle b and that between particle b and particle a, but one is simple minus the other...

Comment: @JimCownie This is a good point, but if we're parallelising the force calculation I'm pretty sure applying that force onto the other particle will lead to a race condition. I could be wrong, though

Comment: There won't be any race condition, you just have to limit the loop on j to `j<i`. However the iterations on `i` will have unbalanced workloads, requiring a specific schedule to get a more efficient parallel execution (could be `dynamic` or `guided`)